# Computing efficiently a small base to the power a large number

Tags: algorithms, exponential-function

Is there a fast algorithm to compute an exponential with a small base, (namely , close to 1) For example, computing 1.01 to the power 100?

Comment: Are you after exact results or results to some level of relative error?

Comment: The exponent needn't be integer, does he?